# Can a Simulacrum of a wizard use the wizard's spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard, equipment, simulacrum

Suppose a wizard casts [*Simulacrum*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum) on their self, creating a duplicate who has all the same spells prepared and has all the same spell slots (minus the 7th level slot used to cast *Simulacrum*, of course). Can the duplicate use the wizard's spellbook to do any of the following?

1. Prepare new spells after a long rest
2. Cast spells as rituals
3. Copy new spells into the book
4. Copy their currently prepared spells into a new book that is then usable by the original wizard

Which of those, if any, is the duplicate capable of doing? Is there anything the duplicate *can't* do with the spellbook that the original wizard can?

Answer (score 5):

Okay - Lots of questions means lots of sources. So lets first look at the main spell, [simulacrum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/simulacrum).

> ... It appears to be the same as the original, but it has half the creature's hit point maximum and is formed without any equipment. Otherwise, the illusion **uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates, except that it is a construct.**
>
> ... The simulacrum **lacks the ability to learn** or **become more powerful**, so it never increases its level or other abilities, nor can it regain expended spell slots.

So the key points are that it's a weaker duplicate of the wizard, and cannot learn.

Now lets see what it takes for a wizard, to cast a spell. Under the [general rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#KnownandPreparedSpells):

> Before a spellcaster can use a spell, he or she must have the spell **firmly fixed in mind**, or must have access to the spell in a magic item. ... Other spellcasters, such as clerics and **wizards, undergo a process of preparing spells**. This process varies for different classes, as detailed in their descriptions.

So wizards prepare spells, and we'll look at that in a moment. First, take a look at [ritual spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Rituals) since that will come up shortly.

> To cast a spell as a ritual, a spellcaster must have a feature that grants the ability to do so. ... The caster must also have the spell prepared or on his or her list of spells known, unless the character's ritual feature specifies otherwise, **as the wizard's does.**

So wizards can cast ritual spells, but they do it differently than others. So let's see what it says about [wizards casting spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#Wizard), both normal and ritual.

> You can change your list of prepared spells when you finish a long rest. Preparing a new list of wizard spells **requires time spent studying your spellbook and memorizing the incantations** and gestures you must make to cast the spell.
>
> You can cast a wizard spell as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag and you have the spell in your spellbook. **You don’t need to have the spell prepared.**

So those are the wrinkles to all of this. Now lets look at the questions again:

*1. Prepare new spells after a long rest?*

For wizards, to prepare a **new** spell, requires studying and memorization. This reads to me as "learning" which a simulacrum cannot do. So there is no way for a simulacrum to learn a new spell, only use the spells in its head at time of creation.

*2. Cast spells as rituals?*

There is nothing stopping it from reading directions from the book--assuming a simulacrum can read your notes. But since you wrote the notes in the first place, and the spell description says that it is the same as the original and has all the same stats, I would say that reading your own handwriting would qualify. And as a bonus, since rituals don't use spell slots, you can cast them repeatedly as a simulacrum cannot regain spell slots.

*3 .Copy new spells into the book?*
*4. Copy their currently prepared spells into a new book that is then usable by the original wizard?*

These I am lumping into the same category. The spell states that the simulacrum "cannot become more powerful". Adding new spells to a spellbook, whether into the existing spellbook or in creating a new one, would fall into the realm of "more powerful". However, since the simulacrum cannot actually **use** the new spell (can't learn it), its up to the DM to decide if that would make the simulacrum more powerful or not.

To the other point, if a simulacrum is tasked with copying a spellbook, they would use the same notation as the original. In fact [the PHB states](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/classes#Wizard):

> **Replacing the Book.**
>   You can copy a spell from your own spellbook into another book—for example, if you want to make a backup copy of your spellbook. This is just like copying a new spell into your spellbook, but **faster and easier, since you understand your own notation and already know how to cast the spell.**"

The simulacrum would copy the spellbook using the same notation as the original so they would not be able to create a spellbook that the original could not read.

So the short answer is, the simulacrum can cast rituals so long as they have the spellbook handy. They cannot change memorized spells ever. And copying spells is DM interpretation.

Comment: IMO, learning means you have no previous memory whatsoever about the knowledge and the "steps" necessary to use said knowledge. In that sense, your **opinion** on the nature of knowledge appears to be flawed to me.  Following that logic, following a map would be the same as looking at the simulacrum's spellbook and being unable to make sense of it from the original's memories.

Comment: I agree with almost everything. The only thing I disagree with are points 3 and 4. You can give the clone a spellbook that he can read with all the spells and that doesn't make it more powerful. It'd make a normal wizard more powerful, thus, writing and copying spells from and to the spell book won't make the clone stronger. It could make the original wizard stronger, but that is not cover in the limitations.

Comment: @Catar4, there is a difference between reading a map and memorizing a spell. Both the map and the spellbook each have a standard language that can be read. But the map can be used without memorization. You don't need to plot out the whole route to use it. Just read it as you need it; exactly like a ritual spell which I agree a sim can do. But the spell requires the whole process to be learned, in full, without error. That's out of scope for a sim.

Comment: @Chepelink, You're right. I reworked my answer to #3 and #4.

Comment: I'm not sure you can lump 3 and 4 together. Copying a new spell (e.g. from another wizard's spellbook or a scroll) requires deciphering the spell, which is arguably learning, but I don't know if that's the case for copying a prepared spell.

Comment: @MivaScott Yeah, there might be a language/symbolic difference but you say it yourself, it relates to memorization which is a different concept than learning. Remembering is not the same as learning new stuff you had no previous knowledge of, that is my point. I can see how you would rule it as a GM, I'm saying I'd rule it differently and so far no answer here bring an answer from an actual D&D source, just interpretations. RAW vs RAI as is often the case in this kind of 'philosophical' question. I'll say I assume "new spells" mean "different spells, previously known", might be wrong.

Comment: @RyanThompson, per the side block for wizards, "Replacing the Book. You can copy a spell from your own spellbook into another book—for example, if you want to make a backup copy of your spellbook. This is just like copying a new spell into your spellbook, but faster and easier, **since you understand your own notation and already know how to cast the spell**."

Comment: @MivaScott It sounds like you're arguing with this comment that the answer to question 4 is yes?

Comment: @Catar4, unfortunately, I don't think you'll have much luck with RAW as this seems to fall into the edge cases that DMs are supposed to decide on their own. Part of the issue with switching spells is that in prior editions, casting a spell literally ripped it from the caster's mind. If you wanted to cast two fireballs, you had to memorize it twice--Very clear cut. In 5th edition it's more a matter of remembering a spell until you don't, at which time you forget it to make room for something else. I akin less to "riding a bike" and more like "study for the test"; learn it just long enough.

Comment: Learning being equal to memorisation is the biggest flaw with schools in the UK.

Answer (score -1):

1. **Prepare new spells after a long rest**

   It can prepare new spells after a long rest as long as the simulacrum has spell slots left:

   > The simulacrum lacks the ability to learn or become more powerful, so it never increases its level or other abilities, nor can it regain *expended spell slots*.
2. **Cast spells as rituals**

   It is a duplicate, so yes it can cast (ritual) spells.

   > You shape an illusory duplicate of one beast or humanoid... The duplicate is a creature, partially real and formed from ice or snow, and it can take actions and otherwise be affected as a normal creature... Otherwise, the illusion uses all the statistics of the creature it duplicates [...].

   Normal spells would require a spell slot of course and rituals won't.
3. **Copy new spells into the book**
   Yes, it is a duplicate, it can do that, as above.
4. **Copy their currently prepared spells into a new book that is then usable by the original wizard**

   I would rule no, that is something you yourself must do:

   > Copying that spell into your spellbook involves reproducing the basic form of the spell, then deciphering the unique system of notation used by the wizard who wrote it. *You* must practice the spell until *you* understand the sounds or gestures required, then transcribe it into *your* spellbook using *your* own notation. (PHB, Spellbook, Wizard Class, Chapter 3)

   If you've ever come across your own (old) notes / code / comments when you've written a complicated design or program and think "How did I write that?" you'll understand this.
   It is also known that writing [helps memorizing](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/68/does-writing-something-down-help-memorize-it).

Comment: How does preparing new spells relate to regaining expended spell slots? There is, AFAIK, no explicit relation between these in 5e. I'm failing to follow your logic on point 2, point 3 is missing, and on 4: why would you rule no, where is the point of ambiguity? You should explain this. Also, cite where your quotes are from. This is particularly important when you quote something other than the spell description in question.

Comment: You're right @Someone_Evil, I've edited the post. If the simulacrum has access to a spellbook it can change it spells.

Comment: If the simulacrum is a duplicate of the wizard who cast it, would they not also be able to practice a spell that wizard wrote and transcribe it into the spellbook using their own notation since it will be identical to the caster's?

Comment: @John  
Is the wizard making a copy of himself (a) or of someone else(b)? Whose spellbook are you writing in? A wizard has to scribe his/her own spells. You can have someone else's spell copied in your spellbook, you still need to encode it yourself if you want to ready it later.

Comment: As per OP: "Suppose a wizard casts Simulacrum on their self"; so for the purposes of this question the wizard is making a copy of themselves. Presumably the simulacrum would be writing in the wizard's spellbook and encoding it using the same notation the wizard uses since the simulacrum is identical to the wizard. (Edit: Just saw the "new book" part; I'd still argue that since the simulacrum wouldn't notate the spells any differently from how the original wizard would that the spells so copied would be preparable and usable)

Comment: I would potentially challenge point #1 though on the basis that a Simulacrum can't learn, so it arguably would be unable to memorise spells, which is a requirement for preparing them. I'll have to look into this further.

Comment: For #3 and #4, the simulacrum would also have that same class feature as the original wizard, saying that they can copy spells into their spellbook (which is also the wizard's own spellbook?) So I'm not sure I see how that text prevents the simulacrum from copying spells. Are you saying the simulacrum needs a separate spellbook that the original wizard can't use? I'm also not sure what the point is about reading one's own old writing. Wouldn't that be equally difficult for the original and the simulacrum?

Comment: @JohnClifford the problem with "practicing the spell" is that is expends spell slots that it cannot recover.  The rest of your point, though, is logical.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I completely agree with you, it would be a terribly inefficient way to make use of a Simulacrum, but still technically possible.